# How to ignore angular 1.6.x promise error avoiding 'unhandled rejections'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

After upgrading to angular 1.6.1 I've faced an issue with promise handling.
Imagine I have following function inside a component:

```
function action(arg) {
  service
    .doRequest(vm.userId, arg)
    .finally(function(){
      vm.called = true;
    });
}
```

Then I have to test success and error path to make sure my `vm.called` property has been set in both cases.
Here the tests:

```
describe('when succeeds', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    spyOn(service, 'doRequest').and.returnValue($q.resolve())
    subject = createComponent();

    subject.action('test arg');
    $scope.$digest();
  });

  it('should set called property to true', function () {
    expect(subject.called).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

describe('when fails', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    spyOn(service, 'doRequest').and.returnValue($q.reject())
    subject = createComponent();

    subject.action('test arg');
    $scope.$digest();
  });

  it('should set called property to true even if something went wrong', function () {
    expect(subject.called).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

When testing the false path, unhandled rejection error is thrown due to [this change](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/c9dffde1cb167660120753181cb6d01dc1d1b3d0) and because I'm not catching any exceptions.

I also know that it can be fixed by:

1. Configuring `$qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);` for test module
2. Adding `.catch(angular.noop)` handler into the subject code to explicitly catch unhandled rejection.
3. modifying original code to return the promise from the `service.doRequest()` call and adding `.catch(angular.noop)` handler into the test itself when calling `subject.action('test arg');`.

Option 1 and 2 aren't acceptable because they will swallow all error which might occur.
Option 3 works for this particular case but will not work if the function already has a return value.

So my question: Is there any way to ignore any errors in the promise chain but avoiding *"unhandled rejection"* errors in tests without using 1-3 options?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of .catch(angular.noop) you should use the angularjs $exceptionHandler https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler to 'handle' your errors, the default just logs to the console but means you aren't swallowing your exceptions and you are still telling angular that you are handling them so you don't get the 'unhandled rejection'. So you could do: catch($exceptionHandler) instead